# Can I use Set-AIPFileLabel to apply a sensitivity label to a file directly in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-information-protection, azure-information-protection

I am wondering if `Set-AIPFileLabel` can be used to apply sensitivity label to a file on SharePoint Online directly (without having to download the file to a local drive - apply label - reupload). I can't seem to find any information on this. Ideally I am looking to apply a sensitivity label (with encryption) automatically, which as far as I am aware is not supported for user-defined permission labels.